# outerHTML data is not complete

Tags: javascript, html, element, outerhtml

**HTML:**

```
<div id="WholeNew">
    <script>func2()</script>
    <img src="x" onerror=func1() />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function func1()
{
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target.parentNode.outerHTML);
}

function func2()
{
    console.log(document.currentScript.parentNode.outerHTML);
}
```

Now look at the output in console:

*For func1():*

```
<div id="WholeNew">
    <script>func2()</script>
    <img src="x" onerror=func1() />
</div>
```

*For func2():*

```
<div id="WholeNew">
    <script>func2()</script>
</div>
```

Why there's a difference in both outputs, as the element in `document.callee.caller.arguments[0].target` of `func1()` `document.currentScript.parentNode` of `func2()` is the same `<div>`? I need complete outerHTML of `<div>` from `func2()`.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't replicate the problem in either IE11 or Chrome51 due to errors. Might have something to do with that callee is deprecated. Not to be pedantic, but what is the problem you're trying to solve with this code, since this doesn't look like the best design imho.

Comment: I can able to run code successfully in Chrome 51 and Firefox 47. IE won't work because of the use of `target`. Use `srcElement`. What error do you get? I'm just experimenting this specific code behavior.

Comment: Depending on where I place the function definitions, I get either caller or callee is undefined. At what location did you palce the script containing the functions? Have you tried this with an actual image url? Maybe the src being 'x' is messing with things.

Comment: I replaced `document.callee.caller.arguments[0].target.outerHTML` with `arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target.parentNode.outerHTML` and now I replicated the issue you have. I can't find any documentation about document.callee though. Anyways, looking around why the outerHTML differs now that I see the issue.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I missed `target` and mistyped `arguments` as `document`. I updated the code.

Comment: Alrighty. since you trigger func2() immediately as the DOM is being parsed, the DOM is still loading. When I switch the script tag and the img tag from place, both fn give the same result. (including the img tag) So I'm thinking in the direction that the img tag won't show up yet in the DOM while it's still being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when asking for `document.currentScript.parentNode` the document is not yet ready. Try to retrieve the `outerHTML` on `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
function func2()
{
    currentScriptReference = document.currentScript;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      console.log(currentScriptReference.parentNode.outerHTML);
    }, false);
}
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/koZ1xDlpFacm7r9uY8lC?p=preview

The result of console log:

```
<div id="WholeNew">
    <script>func2()</script>
    <img src="x">
</div>
```